# SQL Query Report Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I wanted to get the report by date and I want to INNERJOIN the purchased and the item stock but I seems to get it wrong here is my code:

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select month(tblpurchase.PostingDate_p) as mnth,year(tblpurchase.PostingDate_p)
 as yearr,day(tblpurchase.PostingDate_p) as date,tblpurchase.Itemname as itmname, tblpurchase.Quantity as
 pquantity, tblpurchase.Damaged as dmgq, from tblpurchase  INNER JOIN tblitem ON tblpurchase.ItemId = 
tblitem.id where date(tblpurchase.PostingDate_p) between '$fdate' and '$tdate'");
```

Here is my table

tblitem

```
id|ItemName|beginv|stock|PostingDate
```

tblpurchase

```
id|Itemname|ItemId|Quantity|Damaged|LatestInv|PostingDate_p|UpdatingTime
```

Comment: Always provide error message to your code so others can help you troubleshoot. As for this post, I can see you have a `,` before `FROM` which is syntactically wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry. the thing is I want to get the stock on which item is chosen and I've fix the , problem but it doesn't show the stock

Answer (score 0):

Run this one, you dont need a comma after the last reutrned clum

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select month(tblpurchase.PostingDate_p) as mnth,year(tblpurchase.PostingDate_p)
 as yearr,day(tblpurchase.PostingDate_p) as date,tblpurchase.Itemname as itmname, tblpurchase.Quantity as
 pquantity, tblpurchase.Damaged as dmgq from tblpurchase  INNER JOIN tblitem ON tblpurchase.ItemId = 
tblitem.id where date(tblpurchase.PostingDate_p) between '$fdate' and '$tdate'");
```

Comment: Note that, as written, your where construction cannot use an index. (And it's open to injection)